# Generating <link>s for each page in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

I'd like to add `<link>`s to the `<head>` of each of my blog post pages pointing to the next and previous blog posts, e.g. `<link rel="next" href="/blog/my-article/"/>`. This will enable [flip ahead browsing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj883726%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I could use custom front-matter, setting "previousurl" and "nexturl" for each page, and then use those to set the `<link>`s in the default layout. However, I don't want to have to maintain these links by hand, and I'm not able to use page variables in the YAML front matter. Is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel stupid: you can use the page variable, even on the default layout page. So I ended up doing:

```
<link rel="prev" href="{{ page.next.url }}" />
<link rel="next" href="{{ page.previous.url }}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do it using Liquid assign variables.

```
{% assign variable = value %}
```

Comment: I wasn't able to do it with Liquid variables; it might be possible to do it this way, but I couldn't get it to work.